# Can not install mingw libpython in conda ubuntu16

Tags: mingw, ubuntu-16.04, conda, mingw32

Hi: I am using ubuntu 16. after installing latest `conda` for 64 bit machine, and creating environment 'tensorflow' and activating it. I am getting the following error for `conda install mingw libpyhton`

Fetching package metadata.

`PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels:- mingw`

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`mingw` is a Windows-only package as it gives you a "gcc for Windows". On Ubuntu you don't need it. Just install `gcc` with your os package manager, i.e. `apt-get`. `gcc` might already be install. Just type `which gcc` into a terminal to see it it s there.